# How to correctly map a set of data onto a table using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to map data to the correct columns using react and am struggling to get everything to display in the correct column.

Here is my data structure which consists of an array of data - in this original array each object has a norm_data and and feature_data key - which again consists of an array of data with the same keys.

```
[
  {
    "norm_data": [
      {
        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Headline",
        "exists": false
      },
      {
        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Small Print",
        "exists": false
      },
      {
        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Call to Action",
        "exists": false
      },
      {
        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Logo",
        "exists": false
      },
      {
        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Subheadline",
        "exists": false
      }
    ],
    "step_id": 98,
    "cell_id": 38,
    "feature_data": [
      {

        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Headline",
        "exists": false
      },
      {

        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Small Print",
        "exists": false
      },
      {

        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Call to Action",
        "exists": false
      },
      {

        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Logo",
        "exists": false
      },
      {

        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Subheadline",
        "exists": false
      }
    ],
    "stim_id": 345
  },
  {
    "norm_data": [
      {
        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Headline",
        "exists": false
      },
      {
        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Small Print",
        "exists": false
      },
      {
        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Call to Action",
        "exists": false
      },
      {
        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Logo",
        "exists": false
      },
      {
        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Subheadline",
        "exists": false
      }
    ],
    "step_id": 97,
    "cell_id": 37,
    "feature_data": [
      {

        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Headline",
        "exists": false
      },
      {

        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Small Print",
        "exists": false
      },
      {

        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Call to Action",
        "exists": false
      },
      {

        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Logo",
        "exists": false
      },
      {

        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Subheadline",
        "exists": false
      }
    ],
    "stim_id": 344
  }
]
```

This is the closest that i have got so far where I have managed to get where I loop through the  feature_data array to get the labels for the table.

Within that loop I need to somehow loop through the norm data_and the feature_data from into the next two td's - I have labelled where I need the data to go.

```
class Feature extends Component {


  render() {
    const { loading } = this.props;

    if (loading) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    const featureData = this.props.data[0].feature_data;

    return (
      <table>
        <tbody><tr>
          <td></td>
          <td colSpan="2">Title</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td><h2>actual</h2></td>
          <td><h2>norm</h2></td>
        </tr>
        {featureData.map((data, key) => {
          return (
            <tr key={key}>
              <td>
                {data.feature}
              </td>
              <td>I need this to be the feature_data Value</td>
              <td>I need this to be the norm_data Value</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}

        </tbody></table>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the raw markup of how i would like it to look

https://jsfiddle.net/eL0p5zuk/7/

Comment: What is `Actual` value?

Comment: Is the actual value corresponds to `feature_data` meanwhile "norm" is to `norm_data`?

Comment: @ionizer yes sorry my mistake will edit

Comment: I have posted an answer, but I still don't know how you want to format your data exactly, such as what values you want to compare

Comment: @ionizer I have added a JS fiddle of the intended output in raw HTML

Comment: Updated answer... It's a bit hacky than my first one though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming `feature_data` is "Actual" data here (you should clarify that).

I think your problem is your that iterating over `feature_data` only, when in fact you want data from both `feature_data` and `norm_data`.

First, declare the second data array to make it clearer:

```
const normData = this.props.data[0].norm_data;
```

Second, rename the var `key` to `index` to remove any ambiguities: the second argument of a map operation is the index of the iterated item.

If you want to assign this index to the component's key props that's fine, but let the reader keep in mind that it's the index we are talking about.

Then use that index to access corresponding data in the `norm_data`.

So assuming the data you want to display is avg:

```
{featureData.map((data, index) => {
    // data === featureData[index], but I wrote it this way to
    // emphasise the fact that we are using the same index for accessing both arrays
    const featureValue = featureData[index].avg;
    const normValue = normData[index].avg;
    return (
        <tr key={index}>
            <td>
                {data.feature}
            </td>
            <td>{featureValue}</td>
            <td>{normValue}</td>
        </tr>
    );
})}
```

Comment: Ahh yes this is correct - I have a problem where i need to repeat this for each item of the array - at the moment only doing it for the first item - Will need to do for  const normData = this.props.data[1].norm_data; as well

Comment: So each element in form data needs its own new table or just its own row?
For the later just nest loops:
`
    {this.props.data.map((data, index) => {
        data.feature_data.map((subData, subIndex) => {
            return (
                <tr key={`${index}/${subIndex}`}>
                    <td>
                        {subData.feature}
                    </td>
                    <td>{subData.avg}</td>
                    <td>{data.norm_data[subIndex].avg}</td>
                </tr>
            );
        })
    })}
`

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is already spot on as you already passed the index into the map function. Just needed to loop through the actual data with `.map()` as well and then access `feature_data` and `norm_data` inside the `featureData` mapping.

Based on my understanding to your problem though, I can only get you this far:

```js
let data = [
  {
    "norm_data": [
      {
        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Headline",
        "exists": false
      },
      {
        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Small Print",
        "exists": false
      },
      {
        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Call to Action",
        "exists": false
      },
      {
        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Logo",
        "exists": false
      },
      {
        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Subheadline",
        "exists": false
      }
    ],
    "step_id": 98,
    "cell_id": 38,
    "feature_data": [
      {

        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Headline",
        "exists": false
      },
      {

        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Small Print",
        "exists": false
      },
      {

        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Call to Action",
        "exists": false
      },
      {

        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Logo",
        "exists": false
      },
      {

        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Subheadline",
        "exists": false
      }
    ],
    "stim_id": 345
  },
  {
    "norm_data": [
      {
        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Headline",
        "exists": false
      },
      {
        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Small Print",
        "exists": false
      },
      {
        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Call to Action",
        "exists": false
      },
      {
        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Logo",
        "exists": false
      },
      {
        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Subheadline",
        "exists": false
      }
    ],
    "step_id": 97,
    "cell_id": 37,
    "feature_data": [
      {

        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Headline",
        "exists": false
      },
      {

        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Small Print",
        "exists": false
      },
      {

        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Call to Action",
        "exists": false
      },
      {

        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Logo",
        "exists": false
      },
      {

        "avg": 0,
        "panelist": 0,
        "feature": "Subheadline",
        "exists": false
      }
    ],
    "stim_id": 344
  }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td colSpan="2"><h1>Title</h1></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td><h2>Actual</h2></td>
              <td><h2>Norm</h2></td>
              <td><h2>Actual</h2></td>
              <td><h2>Norm</h2></td>
            </tr>
            {
              data[0].feature_data.map((ft, i) => {
                return (
                  <tr>
                    <td>{ft.feature}</td>
                    <td>AVG: {data[0].feature_data.filter(dt => dt.feature === ft.feature)[0].avg}</td>
                    <td>AVG: {data[0].norm_data.filter(dt => dt.feature === ft.feature)[0].avg}</td>
                    <td>AVG: {data[1].feature_data.filter(dt => dt.feature === ft.feature)[0].avg}</td>
                    <td>AVG: {data[1].norm_data.filter(dt => dt.feature === ft.feature)[0].avg}</td>
                  </tr>
                );
              })
            }
            {/*
              data.map((item, i) => {
                return item.feature_data.map((v, j) => {
                    return ( 
                      <tr>
                        <td>{v.feature} {i+1}</td>
                        <td>Data: {JSON.stringify(v)}</td>
                        <td>Data: {JSON.stringify(item.norm_data[j])}</td>
                      </tr> 
                    );
                })
              })
            */}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
table, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

You'll need to structure/format the data output on your own from here as you didn't specify what is being compared, or how you actually plan to format the data.